# Is it possible to implement a keras layer that always propagates a fixed vector to the other layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to develop a neural network architecture that has two inputs. However, I would like to fixate one of these vector inputs during training. I know that this seems to be nonsense for most of you, but I would like to know how to do this for testing a hypothesis.

It is clear that one way to do this would be to prepare a dataset where I simply repeat the fixed value in all instances that I would like. However, this seems to be a bad solution.

I would like to know if it is possible to implement a Keras layer that receives a vector as a fixed parameter and always propagate it to the following layers in each training step when the other input would vary. I'm representing the idea in the image attached.
[image]

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Do you want to modify the fixed vector for every batch/epoch?

Comment: No, @ShubhamPanchal. The ideia is to keep it fixed for all the training process

Answer (score 1):

We can wrap the `tf.keras.backend.concatenate` function, which helps us concatenate the input vector and the fixed vector, in a `Lambda` layer, like,

```py
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np

# A function which concatenates a fixed vector
def concat_fixed_vector( x ):
    # Note, the length of this vector must be the same as the length of
    # the input vector 
    fixed_vector = [[ 1. , 2. , 3. , 4. , 5. , 6. , 7. , 8. ]]
    return tf.keras.backend.concatenate( [ fixed_vector , x ] , axis=0 )

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input( shape=( 8 , ) )
concat_layer = tf.keras.layers.Lambda( concat_fixed_vector )
outputs = concat_layer( inputs )
model = tf.keras.models.Model( inputs , outputs )

print( model( np.array( [[ 1. , 1. , 1. , 1. , 1. , 1. , 1. , 1]] ) ))
```

The output of the code is,

```
tf.Tensor(
[[1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]], shape=(2, 8), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: It seems aligned to what I what. But I would like to create a new kind of layer that could receive a fixed vector as a parameter. Maybe I could extend the Lambda Layer.